# Is this use of character string pointers safe?

Tags: pointers, fortran, standards

While implementing a string utility function, I came across a couple of character pointer expressions that I think may be unsafe. I googled, searched on SO, read my Fortran 95 language guide (Gehrke 1996) as well as various excerpts on display in Google books. However, I could not find any sources discussing this particular usage.

Both ifort and gfortran compile the following program without warning:

```
PROGRAM test_pointer
  IMPLICIT NONE
  CHARACTER(LEN=100), TARGET :: string = "A string variable"
  CHARACTER(LEN=0), TARGET :: empty = ""
  CHARACTER(LEN=:), POINTER :: ptr

  ptr => NULL()
  IF(ptr == "") PRINT *, 'Nullified pointer is equal to ""'

  ptr => string(-2:-3)
  IF(ptr == "") PRINT *, 'ptr equals "", but the (empty) sub string was out of bounds.'

  ptr => empty(1:0)
  IF(ptr == "") PRINT *, 'ptr equals "", it was not possible to specify subarray within bonds'
END PROGRAM
```

The output of the program is:

```
Nullified pointer is equal to ""
ptr equals "", but the (empty) sub string was out of bounds.
ptr equals "", it was not possible to specify subarray within bonds
```

So apparently, the evaluations of the pointer make sense to the compiler and the outcome is what you would expect. Can somebody explain why the above code did not result in at least one segmentation fault? Does the standard really allow out-of-bounds substrings? What about the use of a nullified character pointer?

**edit :** After reading Vladimir F's answer, I realized that I forgot to activate runtime checking. The nullified pointer actually does trigger a run time error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why they do not result in a segfault? Dereferencing a nullified pointer is not conforming to the standard (in C terms it is *undefined behaviour*). The standard does not say what a non-conforming program should do. The standard only applies to programs which conform to it! Anything can happen for non-conforming programs!

I get this (sunf90):

```
 ******  FORTRAN RUN-TIME SYSTEM  ******
 Attempting to use an unassociated POINTER 'PTR'
 Location:  line 8 column 6 of 'charptr.f90'
Aborted
```

and with another compiler (ifort):

```
forrtl: severe (408): fort: (7): Attempt to use pointer PTR when it is not associated with a target

Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              0000000000402EB8  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000402DE6  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          00007FA0AE123A15  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000402CD9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

---

For the other two accesses, you are not accessing anything, you are creating a substring of length 0, there is no need to access the character variable, the result is just an empty string.

Specifically, the Fortran standard (F2008:6.4.1.3) says this about creating a substring:

> Both the starting point and the ending point shall be within the
>   range 1, 2, ..., n **unless the starting point exceeds the ending
>   point**, in which case the substring has length zero.

---

For this reason the first part is not standard conforming, but the other ones are.

Comment: You explained this very clearly. I realize that I forgot to activate run time checks, and that it would have cleared up my confusion about the first case. So then the second and third cases are safe, while the first is not. Thanks!